# Problem with Fatal error: Call to Undefined function filter_var()

Tags: php

I have an error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_var() in /home/example/public_html/register.php on line 17"

My script is like this. And I would like to seek advice as to what the problem is? My PHP version on cPanel is currently set to 5.5.

```
<?php

session_start();
include('config.php');

function validate($post)
{
    if ($post->email == "") return "Email field is required.";
    if ($post->name == "") return "Name field is required.";
    if ($post->password == "") return "Password field is required.";

    if ($_SESSION['captcha'] != $post->captcha) return "Captcha incorrect, please try again.";//this is Line 16
    if (!filter_var($post->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return "That email address is invalid.";//this is Line 17

    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: In this case it would be important to see the file header especially for the namespace and use-statements. Can you try to use the root namespace for `filter_var` by prenending a slash like `\filter_var(..)` and see if the error will go away?

Comment: @ChristophKluge thanks for your reply, how do I do it? Is it like this? (\!filter_var($post->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return "That email address is invalid.";//this is Line 17

Comment: yes. I see that you've followed the answer already from Ronak. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just install phpXX-filter PHP extensions. And restart php-fpm. In FreeBSD, for PHP version 8.2:

```
pkg install php82-filter
```

And then restart the php-fpm service.

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `filter_var` with `\filter_var`

```
if (!\filter_var($post->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return "That email address is invalid.";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. after i replace filter_var with !\filter_var, another error appear: Notice: Undefined index: captcha in /home/invisibl/public_html/register.php on line 16

Comment: if ($_SESSION['captcha'] != $post->captcha) return "Captcha incorrect, please try again.";//this is Line 16

Comment: did you `session_start()` ?

Comment: because session is not set or started use `session_start();` in 2nd line of your code

Comment: @user2192094, do you have `captcha` index into your `$post` object? what `var_dump($post)` would say within your `validate()` function?

Comment: @mitkosoft how do i do it? Do I add "var_dump($post);" in between <?php ?>. I tried and got this - Notice: Undefined variable: post in /home/example/public_html/register.php on line 8
NULL

Comment: @user2192094, add it within your function body, like before your first `if`

Comment: @mitkosoft thanks! it returns this: object(post)#2 (1) { ["properties:private"]=> array(5) { ["email"]=> string(22) "testing190@hotmail.com" ["name"]=> string(10) "testing190" ["password"]=> string(10) "testing190" ["captcha"]=> string(4) "ubuv" ["form_action"]=> string(0) "" } }
Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_var() in /home/invisibl/public_html/register.php on line 20

Comment: @user2192094, now do the same for your `$_SESSION` in order to see what you have there. `var_dump($_SESSION)`. where/how do you set `$_SESSION['captcha']` btw?

Comment: @mitkosoft i added var_dump($_SESSION) below var_dump($post) but it does not returns anything. I think i did not set $_SESSION['captcha'] as global. is this the problem?

Comment: @user2192094, `$_SESSION` is a global array anyway. in which script do you **set** the value of `$_SESSION['captcha']`? do you have there `session_start()` as well?

Comment: @mitkosoft yes, i have session_start();

Comment: @user2192094, better show us the script/page where do you assing a value to the `$_SESSION[‘captcha’]`

Comment: @mitkosoft I have another file captcha.php with the following code: 

<?php
session_start();

$passwd = "";

for ($i=0;$i<4; $i++)
 $passwd .= chr(rand(97, 122));

$_SESSION["captcha"] = $passwd;
?>